# Responsive Webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have added my html code and also my CSS, I am very confused as to how I would go about making this webpage responsive, so when a user is on a different device the webpage auto scales to their device. (Sorry if this is a repeat question, I was not able to find the answer).

```css
       footer {
           margin: 50px 0;
       }

       .fade {
           opacity: 1;
           transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
           -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       }

       .fade:hover {
           opacity: 0.5;
       }

       h1 {
           margin: .67em 0;
           font-size: 2em;
           font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
       }

       body {
           font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
           font-size: 14px;
           line-height: 1.42857143;
           color: #333;
           background-color: #fff;
           padding-right: 5px;
       }

       body {
           max-width: 1000px;
           margin: 10px auto;
       }

       body {
           font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
       }

       body {
           background: white;
       }

       .container {
           max-width: 100%;
           text-align: center;
       }

       .centre {
           position: relative;
           display: inline-block;
           float: left;
           max-width: 100%;
           padding: 50px;
       }

       ul {
           max-width: 100%;
           list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           overflow: hidden;
           background-color: #333;
       }

       li {
           float: left;
           max-width: 100%;
       }

       li a {
           display: block;
           color: white;
           text-align: center;
           padding: 14px 16px;
           text-decoration: none;
       }

       a:hover:not(.active) {
           background-color: #111;
       }

       .active {
           background-color: #4CAF50;
       }

       .accordion {
           width: 895px;
           height: 485px;
           max-width: 100%;
           overflow: hidden;
           box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #111;
           margin: 20px auto
       }

       .accordion ul {
           width: 200%;
           max-width: 100%;
       }

       .accordion li {
           position: relative;
           display: block;
           width: 160px;
           max-width: 100%;
           float: left;
           box-shadow: 0 0 30px 8px #222;
           transition: all 0.4s ease .300ms;
       }

       .accordion ul:hover li {
           width: 40px
       }

       .accordion ul li:hover {
           width: 640px
       }

       .caption {
           background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           width: 640px
       }

       .caption a {
           display: block;
           color: #fff;
           text-decoration: none;
           font: normal 16px'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
           -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
           padding: 10px;
       }

       .center {
           align-content: center;
       }

       .thumbnail {
           display: block;
           padding: 4px;
           padding-left: 5px;
           margin-bottom: 20px;
           line-height: 1.42857143;
           background-color: #fff;
           border: 1px solid #ddd;
           border-radius: 4px;
           -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
           -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
           transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
       }

       .thumbnail > img,
       .thumbnail a > img {
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-left: auto;
       }

       a.thumbnail:hover,
       a.thumbnail:focus,
       a.thumbnail.active {
           border-color: #337ab7;
       }

       .thumbnail .caption {
           padding: 9px;
           color: #333;
       }
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="contain">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Nike_Shoes1.html">Mens Shoes</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="women_clothing.html">Womens Shoes</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="boys_clothing.html">Boys Shoes</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="boys_clothing.html">Girls Shoes</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </nav>


  <div class="container">

    <div>


      <div>

        <div class="accordion">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 1</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#">
                <img src='Slider_Image1.jpg' />
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 2</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#">
                <img src='Slider_Image2.jpg' />
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="caption"><a href="#">Slide 3</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#">
                <img src='Slider_Image3.jpg' />
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div>

        <div class="centre , fade ,">
          <div>
            <a href="Nike_Shoes1.html">
              <img src="Image1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="centre , fade">
          <div>
            <a href="Nike_Trainers.html">
              <img src="Image2.jpg" alt="">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="centre , fade">
          <div>
            <img src="Image3.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="centre , fade">
          <div>
            <a href="boys_clothing.html">
              <img src="Boys_Clothing.jpg" alt="Boys Clothing">
          </div>
        </div>





      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  </div>

  </div>


  <div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>



    </footer>

  </div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a page responsive by adding media queries to the css file, for example:

```
@media(max-width: 800px){
    /* Add mobile styles here */
}
```

You can see more about media queries here, as there are many configs available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I know about media queries but I'm not to sure on how to use them @Luke P

Comment: So in your CSS file, you would have something like this, for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kgoq2pcg/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a responsive webpage by using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) , Flexible grid-based layout for relative sizing and Flexible images.

this book may help you [Responsive Web Design by Ethan Marcotte](https://abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)